# Calling constructor from another constructor and illegal argument exception

Tags: java

for my two parameter constructor to call the four parameter constructor is it proper with what I have done(I am still learning). Also it is supposed to instantiate open interval so is that still correct? for the copy constructor how would I make a copy of the explicit value constructor? Also how do I throw an exception if memory has not been allocated for object being copied?

Comment: Can you first fix it up so that the code compiles? Otherwise it is hard to tell what exactly you are having problems with.

Comment: I added image of code

Comment: I also wha to do  a copy constructor, but it throws an IllegalArgumentException if memory has not been allocated for the object being copied. how would I go about doing that?

Comment: add what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

> for the copy constructor how would I make a copy of the explicit value constructor?

There is no built-in in Java for this. You'd have to manually copy the fields you want to copy

```
public LetsCallThisClassInterval(LetsCallThisClassInterval other){
    this(other.left, other.right, other.stuff)
}
```

But this class looks like it should be immutable, so there is no real need for a copy constructor.

> Also how do I throw an exception if memory has not been allocated for object being copied?

That just does not  happen in Java. Memory is managed for you, and if you get an object reference, it will have been properly allocated already.

Or are you talking about `other` being `null` in the above example?
In that case, you will get a `NullPointerException` automatically. If you prefer an `IllegalArgumentException` (debatable), you can add a null check:

```
if (other == null) 
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("other interval cannot be null");
```

Comment: I am following a design. It says the two parameter constructor must call the four parameter constructor. it also says the two parameter constructor  must instantiate an open interval. is what I did correct for that. Also the copy constructor is supposed to make a copy of the 4 parameter constructor. How do I make a copy of that with the char parameters?

Comment: You can call the 4-param constructor from the copy constructor, using `other.left` and so on for the four parameters.

Comment: yes so after that if statement I can just put             this(other.leftSymbol,other.left,other.right,other.rightSymbol)??

Comment: Ah. Constructor call has to be the first statement. So you cannot put the check in there. You could just copy the code from the four-param constructor into the copy constructor. Or put it into a `private void init()` method (with four parameters). Or just live with the NullPointerException.

Comment: my issue is when I try this(other.leftSymbol,other.left,other.right,other.rightSymbol) it states it cannot see leftSymbol and rightSymbol in the field. However design does not call for them to be fields. so how would I state this????

Comment: you don't have `leftSymbol`, only `leftClosed`. So you cannot call the four-param constructor. Set the four fields directly (`this.leftClosed = other.leftClosed`).

Comment: Im sorry I do not understand. so what would I call then for the copy

Comment: `this.leftClosed = other.leftClosed` copies one of your four fields. You take four of these assignments, and then you have yourself a copy constructor. There is nothing built-in that you could call.

Comment: oh okay all specs say is the copy constructor must throw an IllegalArgumentException if memory has not been allocated for the object being copied

Comment: That could either mean "check for null" or it cannot happen in Java. Poorly written spec (in fact, the whole design is suspicious, this should be an immutable class, with static methods to build instances).

Comment: so I am assuming just check for null if (other == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("null interval"); and jsut leave it at that?

Comment: ah just looke at top of specs and it says it is an immutable interval

Comment: okay nevermind UML does not provide static attributes... ummmm okay

Comment: okay if I have a constains method that returns boolean how would I check to see if a paramter named n is in the interval?

Comment: with out an if statement or a loop

Answer (score -1):

Let me see if I get this right, you want to do a constructor inception? In this case what you would want to do is use the Constructor(//insert the variables that correspond); that should fix the problem.

Using "this" will make the constructor refer to itself, I mean the same method. For example it would be.

```
public Constructor(char leftsym, double left, double right, char rightsymb){
     new Constructor(left, right);
}
```

Now as a side note, the Constructor class already exists between the core classes in Java, I suggest that if you want to simplify your life change your java class name such as Constructor_1 or something like that.

Good Luck

Comment: Using `this( /*...*/ )` is actually the proper (and only) way to call another constructor from within a constructor.

Comment: Actually I already tested the code and It works, but also using this works :)

Comment: okay my two argument constructor is supposed to call the 4 argument and instantiate an open interval. is what I have correct? Also I have a copy constructor that must throw a IllegalArgumentException if memory has not been allocated for the object being copied, but it is not in pic.

Comment: Ok, Well I see no problem with the constructor call but is it necessary to make a constructor for every process? Consider using a method instead. For the object being instanciated I would serialize it and evaluate the object if it´s null it means that it isn´t still instanciated